# How to fix windows or dell recovery on vostro after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, dell

In the begin of this year I have acquired a Dell Vostro 5470 and installed Ubuntu on it. I didn't tried to boot Windows 8 until then, but now I need to, and I can't. (As I am aware now, due to UEFI mode I shouldn't have proceeded as I have been  proceeding for years  to install Linux distros. But as it seems, I did.)

I have already tried Boot-Repair, and it has added some entries to GRUB, but none of them boot Windows. They are now starting Dell recovery System, but this one doesn't succeed in restoring the system either.

I believe that repartitioning the hard drive must have damaged something such that windows and dell recovery doesn't find what they need to work, but I have only redimensioned the  partition originally designed to personal files.

I've read lot of forums, but nothing seems to apply to my case. I'm not in US or Canada, so Dell won't help me with recovery media. Could any one help me?

Here is the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVX-7 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  
Disk Flags:   

Number  Start   End     Size    File system Name                          Flags  
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp  
 2      525MB   567MB   41,9MB  fat32           Basic data partition          hidden  
 3      567MB   701MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres  
 4      701MB   1488MB  786MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag  
 5      1488MB  32,0GB  30,5GB  ext4  
 7      32,0GB  34,0GB  2000MB  linux-swap(v1)  
 8      34,0GB  492GB   458GB   ext4  
 6      492GB   500GB   8097MB  ntfs            Microsoft recovery partition  hidden, diag
```

Comment: You probably removed Windows from your computer. Please add output of `sudo parted -l` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have Windows installed on your computer. You removed it when installed Ubuntu intentionally or not.

But you still have have a Microsoft recovery partition.

You can try to go into UEFI settings and try to find there a recovery option. If that does not work, you will have to re-install Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pilot6! (I thought I were keeping it, but in fact I wasn't really worried about windows at that time.)